# wxWidgets trying to fill whole area

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've got a problem when I'm trying to prepare gui using wxWidgets.
I want to create some buttons which will cover whole area under the textbox.

It looks pretty nice when program starts, but when I want to resize it horizontally the buttons are not moving. Any ideas?

```
    mainFrame::mainFrame(std::string title) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800, 600))
{
wxBoxSizer* vertSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
vertSizer->Add(
        new wxTextCtrl(this, -1, "My text", wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100,80), wxTE_MULTILINE),
        1, // vertically stretchable
        wxEXPAND | wxALL, // horizontally stretchable, borders all around
        10); // Add text box to parent sizer

wxBoxSizer* horizSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL); // Make child sizer, will contain buttons
wxSizerFlags ButtonFlags(1); // Make controls stretch hoizontally (to cover entire sizer area)
ButtonFlags.Expand().Center().Border(wxALL,10); // Make controls expand vertically, add border
horizSizer->Add(new wxButton(this,123,"OK"), ButtonFlags); // Add first button
horizSizer->Add(new wxButton(this, 124,"Abort"), ButtonFlags); // Add second button
horizSizer->Add(new wxButton(this, 125,"Ignore"), ButtonFlags); // Add third button

vertSizer->Add(horizSizer); // Add child sizer to parent sizer
SetSizerAndFit(vertSizer);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you didn't tell your main sizer (`vertSizer`) to grow the `horizSizer` to fill all the available space, you need to add `wxSizerFlags().Expand()` to the one but last line to fix this.

Additionally, using `ButtonFlags.Expand().Center()` doesn't make sense: you can either expand or centre, but not both at once, so choose one. Finally, `DoubleBorder()` is preferable to `Border(wxALL, 10)`.